MingGW installer closes itself?
I tried installing mingw-w64 to start coding in C, after downloading the 'mingw-w64-install.exe'. I ran it, it opened the windows prompt to ask me if I want it to make changes to my device (In which I clicked yes). After that the installer opened, I clicked next, It shows "Getting repository description file". And then just closes, no crash, no errors. Just closes
Any help?

What version of Windows are you on? Some compilers are a bit tetchy about installing on anything less that Win10 or Win11 now. Obviously -w64 needs a 64bit OS. If you are a beginner then you might find the MS VC Community Edition (free) with its IDE a lot simpler to install and use.

I'm on windows 10. And what is the difference between MS VC and the one I tried to download?

MinGW is an easy way to use Linux gcc compiler on Windows. You still need an editor and quirky Unix style make files. MS VC is an entire development environment for native Windows with IDE, syntax directed editor, debugger and profiler (the profiler is rubbish though). Just try not to pick up too many MS bad habits... Once you get experienced Intel's ICX compiler (which will work inside MSVC IDE is probably the best of the bunch). Intel's VTune is the profiler of choice.

For Context, I watched https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrbBmoINqtk There he shows how to download MinGW. I followed every step and somehow it didn't work.

Reading the installation documentation is generally more reliable than watching a video. I don't recall any issues installing MinGW on Win 11 Pro (apart from its glacially slow x87 based floating point library in the default install package).

If you need a recent version of MinGW-w64 you can check out https://winlibs.com/
There you can download a standalone build. No installer, just unzip and start using it.
